# React Jest Async Tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Heres the situation I have a react component, which is grabbing all records via paging in componetDidUpdate. The code functions as intended but I can't seem to get jest expect statements to wait for all async operations to complete.

Component Code

```js
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props !== prevProps) {
   console.log('Componet did update called');
 
      //File ids are grabbed else where and the are populating correctly
   const batchSize = 50;
   for (let idx = 0; idx < fileIds.length; idx += batchSize) {
    const returnedFiles = await getFileVitals(fileIds.slice(idx, idx + batchSize));
    this.doWork(returnedFiles, fileRefs);

    this.setState({
     filesToDisplay: this.files,
     title: Name,
     description: Description,
    });
   }
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the jest test that fails

```js
//DTCQ is where the data serice is implemented
jest.unmock('../../dtcq');
beforeAll(() => {
 dataReaders.getFileVitals = jest.fn();

 dataReaders.getFileVitals.mockReturnValue(mockData);
});


test.only('Component renders proper number of file lines if hiding single revisions.', async () => {
 console.log('Running component render proper number 30');
 const component = mount(<CustomizeTemplate pkg={data.Package} files={data.Files} hideSingleRevisions featureSet={features} buildClicked={jest.fn()} />);

 component.setProps({ featureSet: 'p' });
 component.update();

 console.log('*****Expect Processed');

 // Check that there are 30 file lines, as there are more if not hiding single revisions. 
 await expect(component.find('file-lines').children().length).toEqual(30);
});
```

What is jest method for doing this. I have read through their async documents and not seen any examples doing this type of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a promise to chain in tests. This works best with Enzyme [`disableLifecycleMethods` option](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallownode-options--shallowwrapper):

```
const component = mount(..., { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
const props = component.props();
component.setProps({ featureSet: 'p' });
await component.instance().componentDidUpdate(props);
...
```

Comment: Tried this. Directly calling to componetDidUpdate causes a type error to occur stating that it is not a function.

Comment: Fixed. It should be `component.instance()`.